# Gif image in part indicator of the progress bar control in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
                            <Grid ClipToBounds="True"
                                  x:Name="PART_Indicator">
                                <Rectangle Margin="0,2,0,2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="116" Width="122" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFCCCCCC"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF888888" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="wave_gif.gif" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" >
                                            <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                                    <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        </ImageBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDHZi.gif)

The gif is displayed as an image. I want to replace the rectangle in progress bar with this gif image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58V4T.png)